# Secure netzke rails components

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authentication, netzke

I have a components, cruid for my app, with Netzke

```
class Services < Netzke::Basepack::Grid
```

and view where I run them

```
<%= netzke services %>
```

I secured a controller for this view with simple authentication, and

```
before_filter :authenticate
```

so when I call action index in this controller, which calls a **netzke** cruid for my app, I receive a request to enter name and password.
The question is this enough secured? Maybe I need protect somehow a **netzke** components of my app? Can somebody executed them, bypass my controller index method?

Answer (score 2):

Securing the controller for that view is not enough, as Netzke by default routes its endpoint requests via NetzkeController, which inherits from ApplicationController. If putting before_filter into ApplicationController is not an option for you, then you may tell Netzke to use your custom controller as explained here:

http://rdoc.info/github/netzke/netzke-core/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper